# Brackets in the folder name

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to create a script that runs a file the problem is that the folder where is it has the character "[]" and every time I try to open it displays an error saying that the path was not found... as I would to ignore this character?

```
Sub Main()

If WScript.Arguments.Count >= 1 Then
MyFileSWF = WScript.Arguments.Item(0)
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
oShell.run "CMD /C Start /Max "" ""[ Utilities ]\Flash Player Standalone 18.exe"" " & """" & MyFileSWF & """", 0, True
End If

End Sub
On Error Resume Next
Main
If Err.Number Then
WScript.Quit 4711
End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
"CMD /C Start /Max "" ""[ Utilities ]\Flash Player Standalone 18.exe"" " & """" & MyFileSWF & """"
```

Is being interpreted as:

```
CMD /C Start /Max " "[ Utilities ]\Flash Player Standalone 18.exe" "%swfFile%"
```

Note how the directory name (with square-brackets) is actually excluded from the first quote-enclosed string.

Change it to this:

```
"CMD /C Start /Max ""[ Utilities ]\Flash Player Standalone 18.exe"" """  & MyFileSWF & """"
```

Comment: Thanks to your post I found the problem, the problem is in Start /Max "" should be Start /Max """"